# Слитно или раздельно пишутся "слабо_оксифильный", "максимально_гигроскопическая"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Подскажите, слитно или раздельно пишутся слова "слабо оксифильный", "максимально гигроскопический", например: 1.Большую часть составляют ИЭ с округлыми и округло-овальными светлыми ядрами средних размеров со слабо оксифильной цитоплазмой 2. Цитоплазма их слабо оксифильна. 3.Максимально гигроскопическая влага.

Answer (score 1):

1) Оксифильность —  сродство к кислым красителям, содержащим **кислород**.

**Слабо оксифильный —** раздельное написание наречия со значением слабой степени сродства к кислороду.

**Значение терминов:** Структуры, хорошо окрашивающиеся кислыми красителями, называются оксифильными, а окрашивающиеся основными — базофильными. Эти термины используются при изучение органических структур путем окрашивания.

2) **Гигроскопическая и  максимально-гигроскопическая влага — это термины.**

**Значение терминов: *Гигроскопическая влага  — адсорбированная частицами почвы из атмосферы при её влажности менее 95 %, максимально-гигроскопическая влага адсорбируется почвой из атмосферы с относительной влажностью 95-100 %.

Написание через дефис, так как  существуют две формы записи: **максимальная гигроскопическая влага (два прилагательных) и максимально-гигроскопическая влага** (сложное прилагательное).

Comment: Сомнения по поводу написания "слабо оксифильный"  возникли из-за правила: "пишутся слитно многие сложные прилагательные, употребляемые в качестве научно-технических терминов или выражений в книжном языке, например: азотнокислый, бессрочноотпускной, вечнозелёный, воздушносухой, геологоразведочный, двояковогнутый и т.п.

Comment: Слитное написание "слабооксифильный" по образцу терминов вполне возможно и, скорее всего,  больше подходит в данном случае. Но в текстах встречаются оба варианта, и оба они разрешаются  правилам грамматики. Поэтому существование термина со слитным написанием желательно проверить в специальных словарях или авторитетных источниках.

Answer (score -2):

Оба слова пишутся через дефис: между ними можно вставить союз И.

Comment: Вставить и?! Слабый и оксифильный?! Максимальный и гигроскопический?!

Comment: Да.  А чему вы удивляетесь? Ну, можно попробовать еще "не только..

Comment: Да нет же! Здесь слабая оксифильность и максимальная гигроскопичность.